# What is a split bus panel, and how do I recognize it in the field?

Tags: electrical, wiring, breaker-box, terminology

I'm having trouble identifying a split bus panel. I design and install Solar systems, and lately (after Mr Wiley gave a few seminars to local inspectors) the local authority having jurisdiction (AHJ) are refusing to allow a second feed to a service panel if the utility feed is in the middle of the bus (center). Citing if the panel is a split bus, the 120% rule doesn't apply.

Can anyone confirm what a split bus is and how to identify. is it simply when the feed is in the middle of the bus in the panel?

Comment: See also [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31604), which has pictures of an actual split-bus panel.

Answer (score 14):

Imagine a 2-phase sub-panel: 2 bus bars down the middle, 2 lugs at the top to connecting the incoming power from the main panel. (No main breaker here because this is a sub-panel; the disconnect breaker for this type of panel lives in the upstream panel.)

Now imagine a sub-panel that contains 2 completely independent sets of bus bars. This is a split bus panel.

Here's a picture:

[image: normal panel vs. split bus panel]

Typically, in a split bus panel, the wires delivering the power to the panel are connected directly to the lugs for the upper bus. Then a double-pole breaker is installed on the upper bus and wired to the lugs on the lower bus.

[image: split bus panel wiring diagram]

This is allowed because of the "6 breaker rule", which says that a panel must de-energize all of its circuits by switching off at most 6 breakers. Provided that the upper bus has at most 6 breakers installed (say all double-throw breakers for big appliances) and one of those 6 is the double-pole powering the lower bus, then it takes at most 6 breakers to de-energize all of the attached circuits for the entire panel.

So you can identify a split bus panel by looking in the middle for a (ahem) split bus. It should be obvious because there are lugs buried between the breakers, and those lugs are likely wired to a breaker above.

(In looking for pictures or diagrams to help me explain this, I came across a website from Charles Buell, a home inspector, [that explains a lot about split sub panels](http://buellinspections.com/split-bus-electrical-panels-no-main-breaker), including some mistakes he sees, plus some things that people claim are mistakes but are not. It's a good read and it might help you.)

Comment: actually no, it doesn't require a disconnect breaker upstream.  The whole point of the Rule of Six/split bus panels was that fat 100-150-200A main breakers were prohibitively expensive, and they wanted to do the job with six *much cheaper* 20-70A breakers.  (even today, 20-70A are like $9 and 100+A are $60+++++.) **These panels are hot-wired straight to the meter. The six *are* the disconnect**.

Comment: Note that in situations where the "rule of six" is not applicable, split-bus configurations are still Code-legal, and *still made* by Siemens, primarily for "all-in-one" main/standby applications which integrate a main panel, transfer switch, and standby subpanel into a single enclosure