# Main outdoor breaker is ONLY 100 AMP but total of Breakers AMP on internal panel is 165 AMPs.

Tags: electrical

Main outdoor breaker is ONLY 100 AMP but total of Breakers AMP on internal panel is 165 AMPs.  From what I have read so far this still ok.  I could have Subpanels/Feeder Panels down stream from the main breaker requesting more output but if the Main is unable to handle it then it should "flip off"  correct?

Comment: See the section *Summing Up Breaker Ratings Means Nothing* in [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/31626/33) to the question, [Do the breaker amp readings sum up to dictate my current panels total / possible amperage?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/31604/33)

Answer (score 0):

Synopsis: The sum of all the branch circuit breakers is a meaningless number.

The main breaker will "trip", or "flip off" as you say, when the current (amperage) load well exceeds it's rating for a predetermined amount of time. Meaning a breaker does not trip when the load is 1 or 2 more than the rating. The "continuous load" on the panel should not exceed 80%. In a residential application this is a hard number to pin down though.

As to your sub-panel question, a load calculation is the only accurate way to tell if your service is adequate to support any new loads on the service.