# Can I do two 220V on a single line?

Tags: electrical

I am in the process of adding subpanel. This question is a continuation from my previous [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/133962/what-does-it-mean-to-get-2-phases-of-110v-outlet/134001?noredirect=1#comment215890_134001).

1. Can I do two 220V receptacles on a single 20A line?
2. The equipments will be drawing max 3A and 13A. Is it possible to both on a same line?
3. Can I also use 12/2 cable? or should I use 12/3?
4. Can these receptacles placed in a double outlet box?

P.S:

Top Image: 2 receptacles separated by a junction box and separately placed

Bottom Image: 2 receptacles in a same double housing

[image: 2 receptacles separated by a junction box and separately placed]

[image: 2 receptacles in a same double housing]

Comment: Are you just asking if you can have a 220v [duplex receptacle](https://www.amazon.com/Leviton-5822-W-Receptacle-Commercial-Grounding/dp/B000U3I1S0), because that is certainly a thing.  They're not very common because of the lack of 220v appliances in the US, but they can be found.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, that is one of my question.

Comment: You can also use a [duplex 240V-15A receptacle](https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.15-amp-250v-receptacle-ivory.1000407842.html), because the rules and exception are the same for 240V as 120V - 20A circuits can have 15A receptacles as long as there's more than one of them.

Comment: @Harper Does it mean, I have to have 2 `duplex 240V-15A receptacles`? totaling 4 receptacles.

Comment: No, it means two sockets, so one duplex 15A receptacle will suffice on a 20A circuit.  But if you want 4, go for it.

Comment: A prior answer that gets into the code that @Harper is referring to: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/12125/69176

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do two 220V receptacles on a single 20A line?

Yes, you can.

> The equipments will be drawing max 3A and 13A. Is it possible to both on a same line?

Yes, even if they are continuous loads 16 amps would be allowed.

> Can I also use 12/2 cable? or should I use 12/3?

12/2 is all you need

> Can these receptacles placed in a double outlet box?

Yes.

You can put as many receptacles as you like on a circuit in residential applications. 240 volt receptacles only require 2 wires and a ground wire. Hence the 12/2 wire is sufficient. Circuits are required to be sized for the load they serve. Continuous loads are required to be sized at 125% of the load served. Devices can be placed in the same box without dividers unless the voltage exceeds 300 volts between devices. Which does not happen in residential applications (here in the US anyway).

Good luck!